# Is there a term for the first page of a journal or diary where personal info is punched in?

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a term (if there is one) for the first page of a journal or personal diary or the page where personal information is filled in.

Comment: Punched in? Sounds like a time card at a job....

Answer (score 1):

In a published book, the page with owner information is called the “bookplate”

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I stumbled upon another word for "bookplate". Prolly you already know. **Ex Libris**

Comment: Can you cite a dictionary definition for *bookplate* as a page in a book rather than a pasted label?